# How to get Net surgery trick to work on VGG model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have been trying to apply the net surgery trick to the VGG model. Here's a link to the net surgery trick article:
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb
 However, it seems that the net surgery trick won't produce identical results to the fully connected CNN because the padding on the convolutional layers can't be replicated when feeding in the bigger image. Is there any way to produce identical results in VGG models with net surgery? Any pointers would be great!

Comment: could you add a link for the net surgery trick?

Comment: added link above.